# Countdown timer in Flutter Assistance

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, timer

I am trying to create an app and display a circular countdown timer, however it only works for a second before calling a bunch of other different function, and I am really confused why this is happening. Thank you so much!

**Things I've tried**

- Calling a function that starts the controller - however this starts the timer for like a second and then stops it

Here is the button code

```
GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      currentExerciseIndex ==
                                              widget.exercises.length - 1
                                          ? null
                                          : nextSet();
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                                      color: currentExerciseIndex ==
                                              widget.exercises.length - 1
                                          ? Colors.grey
                                          : Colors.black,
                                      size: size.width * .13,
                                    )),
```

It calls a function called nextSet(), which does this

```
  void nextSet() {
    // Add this method
    if (currentSetIndex % 2 == 0) {
      // new set is a rest set if the index is odd
      print('rest');
      timeMap[currentSetIndex] = elapsedTime; //set time for specific set
      print(timeMap);
      elapsedTime = 0;
      isPaused = true;
    }
    if (currentSetIndex <
        (int.parse(widget.exercises[currentExerciseIndex]['sets']) * 2 - 1) -
            1) {
      isPaused = false;
      setState(() {
        currentSetIndex++;
      });
    } else {
      nextExercise();
    }
  }
```

Here are the final two pieces of information, plus some variables. This is the listview

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        children: List.generate(
                          int.parse(widget.exercises[currentExerciseIndex]
                                      ['sets']) *
                                  2 -
                              1,
                          (index) {
                            var isCurrentSet = currentSetIndex == index;

                            return Card(
                              color: isCurrentSet
                                  ? Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 224, 224)
                                  : Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 66, 66),
                              child: Container(
                                height: isCurrentSet
                                    ? size.height * .15
                                    : size.height * .1,
                                width: size.width *
                                    0.4, // Modify this as per your requirement
                                child: Container(
                                    //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    child: isCurrentSet
                                        ? Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              index % 2 == 1
                                                  ? Row(children: [
                                                      SizedBox(width: 8),
                                                      Text('Rest:',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 20)),
                                                      progress()
                                                    ])
                                                  : Container(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          top: 10),
                                                      child: Column(children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Set: ' +
                                                              ((index ~/ 2) + 1)
                                                                  .toString(),
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 20,
                                                            color: Colors.black,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Container(
                                                            height:
                                                                size.height *
                                                                    .07,
                                                            width:
                                                                size.width * .4,
                                                            child: FittedBox(
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                    formatDuration(
                                                                        elapsedTime),
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontWeight:
                                                                            FontWeight.bold))))
                                                      ]))
                                            ],
                                          )
                                        : index % 2 == 1
                                            ? Center(
                                                child: Text('Rest',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontSize: 20)))
                                            : Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                    'Set: ' +
                                                        ((index ~/ 2) + 1)
                                                            .toString(),
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontSize: 20)))),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

And here are some final variables and functions

```
  late CountDownController controller = CountDownController();

  Widget progress() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //controller.start();
    return CircularCountDownTimer(
      width: size.width * .25,
      height: size.height * .1,
      duration: 60,
      strokeWidth: 10.0,
      fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 203, 12),
      ringColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 52, 52, 52),
      autoStart: false,
      controller: controller,
      onComplete: () {
        elapsedTime = 0;
        nextExercise();
      },
    );
  }
```